# Is it possible to see if the connection parameter is a type of Interface Extension?

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I am looking to execute something dependent on the type of connection it is.  But have not found a way.

```
const onSaveHandler = async (connection: Connection) => { 
  if (connection is serial) { // do serial task }

  if (connection is ethernet) { //do ethernet task }
}
```

All connections have ID, NAME, TYPE,....

```
export interface Connection {
  [CONNECTION_ID_KEY]: number;
  [CONNECTION_NAME_KEY]: string;
  [CONNECTION_TYPE_ID_KEY]: number;
  [CONNECTION_TYPE_NAME_KEY]?: string;
  [CONNECTION_COMM_INTERVAL_KEY]: number;
}
```

Two classes extend:

```
export interface SerialConnection extends Connection {
  [COM_PORT_KEY]: number;
  [BAUD_RATE_KEY]: number;
  [DATA_BITS_KEY]: number;
  [STOP_BITS_KEY]: number;
  [PARITY_KEY]: number;
}

export interface EthernetConnection extends Connection {
  [IP_ADDRESS_KEY]: string;
  [PORT_NUMBER_KEY]: number;
}
```

To see what I am trying to achieve
https://codesandbox.io/s/mbuqb

Comment: That sandbox contains a ton of code that doesn't compile. It's impossible to figure out what doesn't work because it lacks the correct dependencies, and what doesn't work because of the problem you are actually having. Please create [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you want more detailed help here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) here. That means a union of objects that share a common property. That common property then has a different type for each member of the union.

For example:

```
export interface CommonConnection {
  common: string
}

export interface SerialConnection extends CommonConnection {
  connectionType: 'serial'
  COM_PORT: number;
  BAUD_RATE: number;
}

export interface EthernetConnection extends CommonConnection {
  connectionType: 'ethernet'
  IP_ADDRESS: string;
  PORT_NUMBER: number;
}

export type Connection = SerialConnection | EthernetConnection
```

Now you can test the `connectionType` property at runtime, and typescript will cast your value to the right type for you.

```
const onSaveHandler = async (connection: Connection) => { 
  if (connection.connectionType === 'serial') {
    console.log(connection.COM_PORT) // can fetch serial property
  }

  if (connection.connectionType === 'ethernet') {
    console.log(connection.IP_ADDRESS) // can fetch ethernet property
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYQgFsiIlCklhsYEy4BvAKDjm2NKQC44BnGKMgDmTAL5MmoSLEQo0WXHADKaBJgA2FKjTpI4oVEgAmvAhzJbqtes1btKV3QBUAnmGA8A5L1UbPLAgB5AFkAfQAFQIAlJx4kAFciACM0AG4AgCEAQQBVABFQqKynAFE4xJSodPFJcGh4ZFQMHDwSmAALNCoYSx16A2BjU0ISCzJtaz1bNnHHMld3L2AOruX-VgBJcNCsvLyokqUlHn5BJCF01kiY0IA5HOCMkqjy5LSxCSl6uBg3PF7JnAALzKXyaWZ9PQAHzgbU6UG6AN0Ens-DgZCUmAAbsAABKYYzqNDAuCYXguJDYOAACnsE10PCRZAAlMCAHyMOABBDoGl0uZIAB0-MhCzwQIlcG8YM8rOmdjIvAgRMF6ggQlpEMmgvwIQi0ScrIA9Ea2AS4Ohlth2nwwXAwFAIO5YC4AjVWDy+VrdMLvfM-sDJZ5lvDurLGAEFUglSq1RqRdqtjs9gcjsbTdhzZaYNb9CsEct7Y7nb83R8gA)

Comment: This is close to what I need. I have 2 functions that expect SerialConnection or EthernetConnection
addSerialConnection(connection: SerialConnection {}
addEthernetConnection(connection: EthernetConnection) {}

But it states that I cannot add type of Connection to the SerialConnection.

Comment: That's not really enough information for me to help you with that. If you recreate the issue on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play and add a link to your question, then I can probably help you out.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/mbuqb

Answer (score 0):

You can also guess the type without adding anything to your hash, by using [type-predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

```js
    const isSerialConnection = (subject: SerialConnection | EthernetConnection): subject is SerialConnection => {
      return (subject as SerialConnection).COM_PORT_KEY !== undefined;
    };
    
    const isEthernetConnection = (subject: SerialConnection | EthernetConnection): subject is EthernetConnection => {
      return (subject as EthernetConnection).IP_ADDRESS_KEY !== undefined;
    };
    
    const onSaveHandler = async (connection: SerialConnection | EthernetConnection) => { 
      if (isSerialConnection(connection)) { // do serial task }
    
      if (isEthernetConnection(connection)) { //do ethernet task }
    }
```